# Are there any (interesting) consequences of the irrationality of π?

Tags: soft-question, nt.number-theory

I am not sure  how appropriate this question is for MO. If it is not, I apologize in advance but I could not resist asking it and if by any chance I get some interesting answers, it will for sure be very useful to keep my students excited about mathematics and physics as September arrives.

We all know very well that $\pi$ (the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter in Euclidean space) is irrational and even  transcendental. These  are some of the famous results in all mathematics.

So I was wondering what will go wrong if $\pi$  was just an integer number?

> Are
>   there important theorems that are based on the fact that it is actually irrational
>   and/or transcendental?

Comment: Is it the presence of the word "universe" in the title of the question which justifies the mathematical physics tag?!

Comment: Sorry JME, I don't think this question is suitable for MathOverflow. Please, have a look at the FAQ. Maybe you will find there somewhere else where to post this (although I would not know what to suggest).

Comment: This question might be better phrased as "Are there any (interesting) consequences of the irrationality of π?"

Comment: Somewhat related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill

Comment: I've started a meta thread to discuss closing (or not) this question:
http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/601/what-goes-wrong-with-the-universe-if-was-just-an-integer/#Item_1

Comment: http://bible.cc/1_kings/7-23.htm

Comment: I vaguely recall one of my parents mentioning some property of Bessel functions that was proven using irrationality or transcendence of $\pi$.

Comment: Maybe it was Bourget's hypothesis...

Comment: JME: The dependence of the magnetic charge of the monopole on π is subject to which units you choose.  Anyway, π's ubiquity in mathematical physics is not in dispute, but since it is pretty much ubiquitous in other branches of mathematics, I see no reason to single out mathematical physics.  Your question, as I understand it, is whether irrationality/transcendentality of π would have any (physical?) consequences.  I'm still not sure the question does not fall foul of MO's philosophy.


Comment: I have a funny feeling about this question, that there's a fantastic answer lurking out there somewhere.

Comment: I hadn't realized this question was controversial. I've deleted my answer which wasn't strictly an answer anyway.

Comment: Well, regardless of whether this is appropriate for MO, I think it would be a nice question at http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I suspect that a small perturbation and rewording of the original
question is potentially very interesting. My deleted answer
had a flippant component (sorry JME) and serious one. The serious
one gave an answer to the question "what unexpected applications
are there for transcendental  number theory?". 

Answer (score 31):

Since Euler showed that $$\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\prod_{p} \Big(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\Big)^{-1},$$ the fact that $\pi^2$ is irrational implies that there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: Gregory's series http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory's_series for $\pi/4$ also has an Euler product, so the irrationality of $\pi$ itself shows the infinitude of primes.

Answer (score 12):

The fact that π is irrational has few direct applications. However the techniques used to prove this, or rather used to prove the stronger statement that it is transcendental, have many applications. For example, Baker proved that 1 and the logs of algebraic numbers are linearly independent over algebraic numbers except in trivial cases. (This includes the fact that π is irrational as a special case because π = log(-1)/i.) Baker used his theorem to give effective bounds on the solutions of Diophantine equations and to solve Gauss's class number problem for imaginary quadratic fields, among other things. See Baker's book on [transcendental number theory](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=978-0521397919) for more details.

Answer (score 11):

The fact that one cannot square the circle was proven as a corollary of the fact that pi is transcendental. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle

Comment: thanks, but I was expecting 
 less obvious examples

Comment: I was about to write the same answer.  @JME: Next time, you will be probably better off if you include the facts/examples which you are aware of in your question.  It is not very nice to reply “that’s obvious” to a person who answered your question.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi yes, you are  absolutely right. Johan, I am deeply sorry for my heartless comment, it was not in bad spirit.


Comment: No offense taken. 